# Creating Timelines from Row Level Data

Tags: sql, oracle, loops

I'm still a novice to SQL so I'm going to give this a try. Hopefully someone can help! I have the following data set:

[image]

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcGMu.png)

| REQ_NUM | DATE | EVENT | USER_ENTR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23877 | 2022-03-24 00:00:00.0 | Posted | John |
| 23877 | 2022-04-03 00:00:00.0 | Expired | John |
| 23877 | 2022-05-03 00:00:00.0 | Posted | Jane |
| 23877 | 2022-05-09 00:00:00.0 | Expired | Jane |
| 23877 | 2022-05-27 00:00:00.0 | Posted | John |
| 23877 | 2022-06-17 00:00:00.0 | Unposted | John |

Basically, what I am trying to do is create a row for each start (posted) and end (expired, unposted) date like so:

| REQ_NUM | START_DT | END_DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23877 | 2022-03-24 00:00:00.0 | 2022-04-03 00:00:00.0 |
| 23877 | 2022-05-03 00:00:00.0 | 2022-05-09 00:00:00.0 |
| 23877 | 2022-05-27 00:00:00.0 | 2022-06-17 00:00:00.0 |

This will be used to calculate time posted between stints as well as trending when a requisition was actually posted for candidates to apply.

I think I need to use some kind of loop, but I don't even know where to start honestly. I've tried searching but I don't think I really know what to search for so even just a clue of what I need to look for would help.

I appreciate any help you can provide!

I thought maybe a grouping with min and max dates, but there are gaps before requisitions were even posted again so it's misleading.

Comment: Hi - you probably just need to use the LEAD (or LAG) function

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a currently supported Oracle version, so it should support `match_recognize`:

```
select *
from your_table
match_recognize (
   partition by req_num
   order by trans_date
   measures
      first(trans_date) as start_dt,
      last(trans_date)  as end_dt,
      last(event)       as end_event
   pattern (start_ next_+)
   define
     start_ as (event='Posted'),
     next_ as (event!='Posted')
)
```

Full DBFiddle example: https://dbfiddle.uk/4Fai2-ZQ

Answer (score 0):

If your actual data looks like in the question - you could use conditional [LAG() and LEAD() analytic functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions) to get starting and ending dates in the same row.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
          REQ_NUM,  
          CASE WHEN EVENT  = 'Posted' THEN A_DATE ELSE LAG(A_DATE)  OVER(Order By REQ_NUM, A_DATE) END "START_DT", 
          CASE WHEN EVENT != 'Posted' THEN A_DATE ELSE LEAD(A_DATE) OVER(Order By REQ_NUM, A_DATE) END "END_DT"
FROM      tbl
```

... which with the sample data ...

```sql
WITH
    tbl (REQ_NUM,   A_DATE, EVENT,  USER_ENTR) AS
        (
            Select  23877,  To_Date('2022-03-24', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),    'Posted',   'John' From Dual Union All
            Select  23877,  To_Date('2022-04-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),    'Expired',  'John' From Dual Union All
            Select  23877,  To_Date('2022-05-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),    'Posted',   'Jane' From Dual Union All
            Select  23877,  To_Date('2022-05-09', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),    'Expired',  'Jane' From Dual Union All
            Select  23877,  To_Date('2022-05-27', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),    'Posted',   'John' From Dual Union All
            Select  23877,  To_Date('2022-06-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),    'Unposted', 'John' From Dual 
        )
```

... should result with:

```sql
   REQ_NUM START_DT  END_DT  
---------- --------- ---------
     23877 24-MAR-22 03-APR-22 
     23877 03-MAY-22 09-MAY-22 
     23877 27-MAY-22 17-JUN-22
```

Note: The DISTINCT keyword eliminates duplicated rows and could be performance costly with large datasets.